# Fetching JSON data from API with Python in Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-views

I'm trying to get data from API with GET query in Django. I get as response HTML-code, where the JSON is included too. It seems like Content-Type header isn't working and that's why I get HTML-code as response.

I tested to do queries with Postman:

- When I didn't have Content-Type header at all, I got same HTML-code
  as now.
- When I have Content-Type header as text/json, it responded
  with JSON-data.

**Here is my code at views.py, I don't expect this to work on website yet, so I don't return/render anything**

```
def json_search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    final_url =  urllib2.Request('http://APIwebsite.com', None, {'Content-Type':'text/json'})
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('username', 'password')).replace('\n', '')
    final_url.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
    decoded_data = json_obj.read()
    print decoded_data
```

As response I get HTML-page code, with CSS and JSON-data. How I can get just only the JSON data?

Comment: I believe the `Content-Type` should be `application/json` rather than `text/json` and json.loads call should work on the returned response. Also, what's the python version that you are using?

Comment: No change for me. I'm using 2.7.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML-page had a link to page, where is only the JSON-code. So, I made query to that page, and it works. Though, I have made the same query with Javascript and it worked with correct Content-Type header.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a utility method and pass the arguments in that, for example

```
class JsonResponse(HttpResponse):
    '''
        Handling content type for json no more to add content-type.
    '''

    def __init__(self, content={}, status=None,content_type='application/json'):
        super(JsonResponse, self).__init__(
            json.dumps(content),
            status=status, content_type=content_type)
```

after this you just need to pass the data to the above method like

```
response_json.update({"message": "success"})
return JsonResponse(response_json)
```

This might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
json.loads(request.body)
```

Json responses can be handled using this way.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you, but I get error that attribute body doesn't exist. Without it, I get error "TypeError: expected string or buffer".